# Why do my brand new LED lights work fine sometimes but sometimes are dim with dark spots?

Tags: led, light

I have 2 4ft LED light tubes in my kitchen, sometimes they turn on just fine and work all day but some days they only turn on half way, both of them are very dim and one of them has a dark spot in the middle with no light at all.

They are brand new and go back and forth between working and then not working, so should I just buy some more, maybe go back to fluorescent tubes, or do I need an electrician or can I fix it myself?

Comment: Brand new, does not work right - likely defective. How easily that's fixed (by replacement, or return and upgrade to better quality) will depend on whether they are a reputable brand of quality product, or cheap junk drop shipped from the far side of the globe that may not even meet basic safety standards, much less have quality control (there's a LOT of that in the marketplace these days.) Fluorescent tubes with a decent ballast are actually still a good option.

Comment: Definitely contact the seller to talk about a refund/replacement. This sounds very much like a defective product. Depending on the reputation of the brand, it could be a rare slip-up in quality control, or it could be what you're going to get from this particular manufacturer.

Comment: LED replacement "fluorescent tubes" are some of the flakiest products on the market.  Especially if they're "no-name" or "name I've never heard of before that's [very well reviewed](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-54055669) on Amazon". Or [ANYTHING from Amazon](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2019/11/14/how-amazons-quest-more-cheaper-products-has-resulted-flea-market-fakes/) lol.

Comment: Are these tubes direct wire or ballast compatible? The problem with ballast compatibility is the ballast has to work and even when they work sometimes there are issues. If the ballast is failing the problem won’t be fixed with new LED’s or fluorescent tubes.

Answer (score 1):

Some LED fixtures have a feature wherein you can select a brightness level. You do this by rapidly flicking the switch on and off, i.e. once for full brightness, twice for half brightness, which for LEDs, might mean fewer LEDs are excited. Mine has 3 levels, the third being a warmer light color temperature. Try flicking the switch twice and see if it changes.